# RxJava just() computation thread

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

Im confused. I have a method which do some longtime job (about 5 second) and returns a `String` as a result.
I wrapped that function into an `Observable` smth like this:

```
private Observable<String> getJobObservable() {
    return Observable.just(doJob());
}
```

But even with `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())` and `.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())` my `doJob()` method calculates on `mainThread`
But, after i have changed `Observable.just()` to `Observable.fromCallable()` everything works fine.
Why `Observable.just()` doesn't react on thread changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you write

```
return Observable.just(doJob());
```

that is equivalent to

```
Object o = doJob();
return Observable.just(o);
```

Now if you don't have `Observable.just(o)` at all, where does `doJob()` execute? Just because `doJob()` or `o` are put into between the parenthesis of `just`, it doesn't mean somehow the whole execution of `doJob` gets deferred, unlike when you ensure it via `fromCallable`.